# verificar se valor existe no array, se nao existir gravar os dados que nao existem em outro array

Tags: php, array

```
$array      = array(
            'b_E_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'_A.'.$ext,
            'b_M_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'_A.'.$ext,
            'b_M_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'_B.'.$ext,
            'b_M_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'_C.'.$ext,
            'b_G_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'_A.'.$ext,
            'b_G_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'_B.'.$ext,
            'b_G_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'_C.'.$ext,
            'b_M_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'.'.$ext,
            'b_M_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'.'.$ext,
            'b_M_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'.'.$ext,
            'b_G_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'.'.$ext,
            'b_G_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'.'.$ext,
            'b_G_'.$cnpjClie.'_'.date('Ymd').'.'.$ext
        );
        $str = implode("<br>", $array);

        if (in_array($NewArquivo, $array)):
            echo "<b>CNPJ: </b>" . $cnpjClie . "<br>";
            echo "<b>REALIZOU: </b> BACKUP HOJE<br>";
            echo "<b>Arquivo: </b>". $arquivo . "<hr><br>";
        else:
            echo "<b>CNPJ: </b>" . $cnpjClie . "<br>";
            echo "<b>PENDENTE: </b> de backup!<hr><br>";
            //$arrayC   = array($cnpjClie); tentado assim, corrigido abaixo
            $arrayC[] = $cnpjClie;
            $strC     = implode("\n", $arrayC);
        endif;
```

Gostaria de saber os dados que nao estao no array, e armazenar em outro array no caso $arrayC[], afim de ao final poder notificar quem nao efetuou o backup no dia, no teste que tentei ali, ele repete os mesmos dados no ELSE.

Answer (score -1):

Você deve utilizar um laço de repetição na variavel $array, aí dentro do laço de repetição você faz seu if para verificar o in_array(). Assim quando ele cair no else você adiciona o conteudo não encontrado na variavel $arrayC[]

Answer (score -1):

```
// Duas estruturas de dados unidimensional
$array_a = array('A','B','C','D','E','F');
$array_b = array('Z','C','X','F','D');

// Estrutura de dados com a intersecção dos arrays acima.
$array_intersect = array_intersect($array_a,$array_b);
var_dump(array_intersect($array_a,$array_b));

// Mescla dos dois arrays originais, ou seja todos os valores em uma estrutura da dados.
$array_ab = array_merge($array_a, $array_b);
var_dump($array_ab);
// Removendo valores duplicados.
$array_ab = array_unique($array_ab);
var_dump($array_ab);

// Verificar se cada item está na interseção
foreach($array_intersect as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $array_ab)){
        // Se estiver remove pois só queremos os itens novos, ou seja, que não existe nos dois arrays.
        unset($array_ab[$key]);
    }
}

var_dump($array_ab);
```

Obs: Cuidado com "in_array", se caso seja passado true, ver documentação (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php)

E cuidado pois o exemplo acima só funciona para duas estruturas de dados unidimensional...

**E cuidado com as chaves, pode dar diferença na remoção unset().

Espero que tenho ajudado =/